# Декораторы в Python

Tags: python

Есть код:

```
def decorator_maker_with_arguments(decorator_arg1, decorator_arg2):
    print("Я создаю декораторы! И я получил следующие аргументы:",
          decorator_arg1, decorator_arg2)
    def my_decorator(func):
        print("Я - декоратор. И ты всё же смог передать мне эти аргументы:",
              decorator_arg1, decorator_arg2)
        # Не перепутайте аргументы декораторов с аргументами функций!
        def wrapped(function_arg1, function_arg2):
            print ("Я - обёртка вокруг декорируемой функции.\n"
                   "И я имею доступ ко всем аргументам\n"
                   "\t- и декоратора: {0} {1}\n"
                   "\t- и функции: {2} {3}\n"
                   "Теперь я могу передать нужные аргументы дальше"
                   .format(decorator_arg1, decorator_arg2,
                           function_arg1, function_arg2))
            return func(function_arg1, function_arg2)
        return wrapped
    return my_decorator
```

Совсем не понимаю, почему

```
print("Я создаю декораторы! И я получил следующие аргументы:",
      decorator_arg1, decorator_arg2)
```

Выполняеться только при "инициализации" декорированой функции, а не при каждом её вызове?

Comment: Так при вызове декорируемой функции вызывается по факту не `decorator_maker_with_arguments`, а `my_decorator`, который она вернула.

Comment: insolor, спасибо, а почему так?

Comment: Даже не так. `decorator_maker_with_arguments` создает декораторы - она вызывается когда создается декоратор. `my_decorator` - сам декоратор, он вызывается один раз, когда декоратор применяется к функции. `wrapped` - это "обертка" вызывается каждый раз при вызове декорируемой функции. Почему так - потому что так это работает) Может быть кто-то более аргументированно напишет.

Comment: Можете почитать про паттерн проектирования "декоратор". Декоратор возвращает объект с новой функциональность (декорированный объект). Дальше новые функции объекта можно использовать сколько угодно раз, при этом каждый раз не создавая новый декорируемый объект. Можно сказать что decorator_maker_with_arguments это класс-декоратор, my_decorator - новая функциональность,

Answer (score 0):

Основное свойство декораторов это то, что они выполняются сразу после определения декорируемой функции, например прямо на этапе импорта. Декоратор выполняется однажды для каждой декорированной функции дабы расширить ее функциональность, вот например декоратор, который может облегчить маршрутизацию, собрав необходимые элементы в одном месте:

```
>>> my_func = [] 
>>> def decor(fun):
...   print("I'm decorator")
...   my_func.append(fun)
...   return(fun)
... 
>>> @decor
... def a(val):
...   return val + 1
... 
I'm decorator  # мы еще не успели обратиться к функции, но она уже в нашем списке
>>> a(1)
2
>>> my_func
[<function a at 0x7f27deca00d0>]
>>> @decor
... def b(val):
...   return val + 1
... 
I'm decorator  # Тоже самое, смотрим my_func, b уже там 
>>> my_func
[<function a at 0x7f27deca00d0>, <function b at 0x7f27deca0e18>]
>>> my_func[1]()  # Мы обращаемся к b, что-то забыли?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: b() missing 1 required positional argument: 'val'
>>> my_func[1](12)  # Да, это b и она ожидает аргумент
13
```

А вообще обратите внимание на замыкания и пространство имен, вот пример замыкания:

```
>>> def a():
...   q = []
...   def b(w):
...     q.append(w)
...     return q
...   return b
...  
>>> aa = a() 
>>> aa
<function a.<locals>.b at 0x7f27deca0ea0>
>>> aa(1)
[1]
>>> aa(2)
[1, 2]
```

Comment: выполняются сразу Перед определением декорируемой функции, и даже после, если необходимо

Answer (score 0):

Декоратор -это самая обычная функция, которая содержит и возвращает замыкание.

Все остальное зависит от способа декорирования, с `@` или без:

```
# print сработает один раз
@decorator_maker_with_arguments(1, 2)
def qwe1(*a):
    pass
qwe1(3, 4)
qwe1(3, 4)


# print сработает каждый раз
def qwe2(*a):
    pass
decorator_maker_with_arguments(1, 2)(qwe2)(3, 4)
decorator_maker_with_arguments(1, 2)(qwe2)(3, 4)


# или так
a = decorator_maker_with_arguments(1, 2)
b = a(qwe2)  # b - это аналог варианта декорирования с `@`
b(3, 4)
```